# JSONModel DATE transformers is nil

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, jsonmodel

From ASP MVC API JSON I have this date

...
expdate: "2013-11-16T21:16:15.4302648-08:00"
...

I have this model

```
@interface DateModel: JSONModel

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate* expdate;


@end
```

But returns nil I tried changing the data type to string for testing and returns the date string, why transformers is not kicking? ..

Comment: Can you show your code how did you tried??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately in this version JSONModel does not support milliseconds in the dates by default. You can see how to implement a date parser featuring milliseconds and more here, just follow the conversation:

https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel/pull/123